# SMD diodes with mark YR103, WX104, and RZ102

Tags: diodes, identification, surface-mount

I'm trying to identify the SMD components on a contactor control circuit.  They are from General Semiconductors and have the labels: YR103, WX104, and RZ102.  I think they are diodes, but I'm not sure what kind.  Can I get some help with identifying them?

[image: PCB]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the marking guide for Vishay's power diode division, formerly General Semiconductor:

[Vishay PDD marking guide](http://www.vishay.com/docs/88912/pddmarking.pdf)

If your parts are General Semi diodes you should be able to figure out what they are from there, based on what kind of package they are in.  (SMA, D-Pak, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for the link, I think I'm getting a little closer.  From the marking guide, these seem to be TVS diodes.  Now to determine the type codes...

Comment: I'm curious if this chart applies to my diodes? http://www.s-manuals.com/pdf/datasheet/s/m/smaj_littelfuse.pdf  (page 2)

Comment: Nevermind, I found the correct datasheet here: http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/548547.pdf  I'm gonna select this as the answer, thanks John D!

Comment: that link is broken